# How to replace specific string in a file name using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to write a powershell script which go to specific folder which have multiple folders containing Excel file. File name is as example 
1_RIM_Reports_201510.xlsx
2_Rim_Reports_September.xlsx

Now I want to change replace the word RIM with NIR how can i do that for multiple files.

1_NIR_Reports_201510.xlsx
2_NIR_Reports_September.xlsx

```
Get-ChildItem $directory -Recurse |

    Rename-Item { $_.name -replace '*RIM*.xlsx', '*NIR*.xlsx' }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your string always have the the underscore `_` before and after you can simply use this:

```
Get-ChildItem $Directory -Recurse | 
Foreach-Object { Rename-Item $_.FullName ($_.FullName -replace "_RIN_","_NIR_")}
```

Otherwise you need to use Regular Expression, if this is the case let us know

Comment: Thanks it helped !! :)

Comment: how do you change the words in file if the word say RIM OLD Reports for consolidation how can i chagne it to RIM OLD Reports for consolidation?

Comment: Change the first section (before the comma) to any chars you like and the end section (after the comma) to the result you want `"_RIN_","_NIR_"`